# "Yes No Yes No" task from Codewars

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

https://www.codewars.com/kata/573c84bf0addf9568d001299/train/python

The task:

"Write a code that receives an array of numbers or strings, goes one by one through it while taking one value out, leaving one value in, taking, leaving, and back again to the beginning until all values are out.

It's like a circle of people who decide that every second person will leave it, until the last person is there. So if the last element of the array is taken, the first element that's still there, will stay.

The code returns a new re-arranged array with the taken values by their order. The first value of the initial array is always taken."

Examples:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
// returns [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 6, 10, 8, 4]

var arr = ['this', 'code', 'is', 'right', 'the']
// returns ['this', 'is', 'the', 'right', 'code']
```

My code is:

```py
def yes_no(arr):
    arr1 = []

    if len(arr) == 0:
        return arr1

    for i in range(len(arr)):

        if i % 2 == 0:
            arr1.append(arr[i])

    for j in arr1:
        arr.remove(j)
    yes_no(arr)
```

Comment: Where does you code fail? What does it do wrong?

Comment: I think you should do `return arr1 + yes_no(arr)` instead of `yes_no(arr)`.

Comment: The wikipedia page on this problem includes an efficient solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `arr.remove(j)` because there can be duplicate numbers, say an example case as `[1,2,3,4,5,20,6,7,8,20]`.

---

I solved this in `javascript` but since you mention `algorithm` tag, answers can be `language-agnostic`.

**Approach:**

We can create a **circular doubly linked list** of the given numbers. So, for `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, the list would look like:

```
                                                                    _____
                                                                   |     | 
      both next and prev links(double arrow notation)              v     |
  -1 <--> 2 <--> 3 <--> 4 <--> 5 <--> 6 <--> 7 <--> 8 <--> 9 <--> 10 --  | prev link
 | ^                                                                  |  |
 | |_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _next link_ _ |  |
 |_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```

For each step, we add the current value of the node in iteration to result. Before moving on to the next to next node(because we skip in the middle), we would do below 2 steps:

```
  temp.prev.next = temp.next;
  temp.next.prev = temp.prev;
```

which means that we assign previous node's `next` value to next node of current node and next node's previous value to current node's previous value.

After first step of iteration, our new(as in modified) circular DLL would look like below:

```
                                 ______                                   
                                |      | 
    both next and prev link     v      |
  -2 <--> 4 <--> 6 <--> 8 <--> 10 --   |
 | ^                                |  |prev link
 | |_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _next link_ _ _ |  |
 |_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```

Likewise, you can generate how the list would look like for each step.

**Snippet:**

```js
function yesNo(arr) {
  var result = [];
  var head = null,
    temp = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (head == null) {
      head = createNode(arr[i]);
      temp = head;
    } else {
      var temp2 = createNode(arr[i]);
      temp.next = temp2;
      temp2.prev = temp;
      temp = temp2;
    }
  }

  temp.next = head;
  head.prev = temp;
  temp = head;
  while (temp.next != temp) {
    result.push(temp.value);
    temp.prev.next = temp.next;
    temp.next.prev = temp.prev;
    temp = temp.next.next; // skip next and go to next to next
  }

  result.push(temp.value);
  return result;
}

function createNode(val) {
  return {
    value: val,
    prev: null,
    next: null
  };
}

console.log(yesNo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])); console.log(yesNo(['this', 'code', 'is', 'right', 'the']));
```

**Time Complexity:** O(n)

**Space Complexity:** O(n)

where `n` is number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a deque (from collection) by alternatively poping and rotating entries in the queue:

```
from collections import deque

arr    = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

result = [ (q.popleft(),q.rotate(-1))[0] for q in [deque(arr)] for _ in arr]
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 6, 10, 8, 4]
```

You could also create a function that will compute the indexes in the right order and return elements at these indexes:

```
def skipOrder(arr,skipBy=1):
    N = len(arr)
    b = 2**N-1         # bits of unskipped posiitons
    pos = skip = 0     # current position and skip cycle
    while b:
        if b&1:                        # remaining position
            if not skip:               # yield and clear if not skipped
                b ^= 1
                yield arr[pos]
            skip = (skip+1)%(skipBy+1) # cycle skipping
        b   = ((b&1)<<(N-1)) | (b>>1)  # rotate positions bits
        pos = (pos+1)%N                # and index


result = list(skipOrder(arr)) # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 6, 10, 8, 4]
```

It uses the a similar principle to the queue (yield, skip, rotate) but does it on bits of a number instead of moving actual elements in a data structure.